# JQuery Append UL to another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this DIV:

```
    <div id="video_container" class="barra">
        <ul>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Gy3lrgVakII" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AnwKqlhzCM4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/wLJM0oi7o9A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NRWrYGaqIO8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ICUhpeXDrwQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/DDVWXbVxIkI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ntD69DBs8Q8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fuTmK5WHQ18" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/IpUwiyID_Kk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/snISa71nM_k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/z6VuNTPuChc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
            <li><iframe width="450" height="253" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NKzwcbidanM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="video_container_mobile"></div>
```

i want to populate another div with the same content `(<ul>...</ul> )`

I have this:

```
var list = $("#video_container_mobile").append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
        $("#video_container ul li").each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            list.append(el);
        });
```

This works, but this erasing from the original div, the list that i was appending.

See the image below:

[image: THE IMAGE FROM FIREBUG]

and see the FIddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YgQJM/

I want to keep in the 2 DIV's the same content... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not as clean as @Hussein's, but

```
$('#video_container_mobile').append($('#video_container').html());
```

Comment: actually it is good .. but it's only problem is that it get's the contents without the parent  . :(

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#video_container_mobile').append($('#video_container ul ').clone())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edY45/